# Trigonometric Integrals problem

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

So when we have trigonometric integrals of the form 
$$ \int \sin^mx\cos^nx\, dx.$$ 
And

- if $m$ is a even integer(positive or negative) and $n$ is a negative odd integer then we use sub : $\sin x = t$ 
  or
- $n$ is a negative odd integer and $m$ is a even integer(positive or negative). Then we use sub: $\cos x = t$. 
  Is this correct?

Comment: Both of your cases appear to be identical. $m$ is even and either positive or negative, and $n$ is odd and negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always try out each case. For instance:

- If both $m$ and $n$ are negative integers, with $m$ even and $n$ odd, then

$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sin^mx\cos^nx}=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sin^{2k}x\cos^{2\ell-1}x}=\int\frac{\cos x}{\sin^{2k}x(1-\sin^2x)^\ell}\,\mathrm dx$$

where $m=2k$ and $n=2\ell-1$ for some positive integers $k$ and $\ell$. Substitute $t=\sin x$ and $\mathrm dt=\cos x\,\mathrm dx$ to get

$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sin^mx\cos^nx}=\int\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^{2k}(1-t^2)^\ell}$$

- If instead we take $m>0$, then

$$\int\frac{\sin^mx}{\cos^nx}=\int\frac{\sin^{2k}x}{\cos^{2\ell-1}x}=\int\frac{\sin^{2k}x\cos x}{(1-\sin^2x)^\ell}\,\mathrm dx$$

The same substitution leads to

$$\int\frac{\sin^mx}{\cos^nx}=\int\frac{t^{2k}}{(1-t^2)^\ell}\,\mathrm dt$$

The other case with its two sub-cases can be handled similarly (assuming you meant to swap $m$ and $n$ in the latter case).

Comment: Yes i see thank you very much.